# How to read/edit a .txt file that has html tags

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to clean a .txt file of html tags. I have the content of this link saved to a .txt file.

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1630970/000149315218014686/0001493152-18-014686.txt

I want to remove the html tags, but having trouble having the actually reading / writing the file.

I've just tried opening the file before processing it with BeautifulSoup.

```
f = open('test_file.txt',"r")
print(f)
```

returns:

```
<_io.TextIOWrapper name='test_file.txt' mode='r' encoding='UTF-8'>
```

The desired output would print the file. Feeling slightly crazy for not being able to open this.

Comment: You can use the open file points's read method `print(f.read())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a proper HTML parser like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) you can remove the HTML tags and get the text only easily:

```
from pathlib import Path
import BeautifulSoup
contents = Path(file_path).read_text()
soup=BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(contents)
print soup.text
```

Note that the above is Python 3 code

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're printing out the file object returned by [`open`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value), not the text that the file represented by the object contains.

You need to tell it to read the file. The simplest ways of doing that are using [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines), or, as the documention notes, just iterate the object directly:

```
for line in f:
    print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file natively.  Like this.  You are missing the .read

```
f=open("test_file.txt", "r")
if f.mode == 'r':
    contents =f.read()
print(contents)
```